# Why did our AWS Aurora RDS spike and lock up?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds-aurora

This morning our aurora mysql serverless 2 spiked and basically locked up. We have a writer/reader and a reader associated with the cluster.

On the reader we had an intense select query. This is the query RDS shows (field names changed), the point is it has multiple FIND_IN_SET functions and insights show it examined 109826.50 rows.

SELECT `thisstuff` ( `thistime` ) AS `thestuff` , COUNT ( * ) AS `count`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `todo` = ?
AND `someID` = ?
AND
( ( `FIND_IN_SET` ( `otherID` , ? ) ) ||
( `FIND_IN_SET` ( `otherID` , ? ) ) ||
( `FIND_IN_SET` ( `otherID` , ? ) ) )
AND ( `thistime` BETWEEN ? AND ? )
AND `some_status` = ?
GROUP BY `months_todo` ( `thistime` )

At the same time our writer had the following waits going on.

wait/io/redo_log_flush
synch/sxlock/innodb/hash_table_locks
wait/io/table/sql/handler

Can somebody please help me understand why this happened, as in did the writer lock the tables or did the FIND_IN_SET lock the writer? The writer was making updates to the same table at the time the query was going on. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  thisstuff ( thistime ) AS thestuff , COUNT ( * ) AS count
    FROM  mytable
    WHERE  todo = ?
      AND  someID = ?
      AND  ( ( FIND_IN_SET ( otherID , ? ) ) ||
             ( FIND_IN_SET ( otherID , ? ) ) ||
             ( FIND_IN_SET ( otherID , ? ) ) 
           )
      AND  ( thistime BETWEEN ? AND ? )
      AND  some_status = ?
    GROUP BY  months_todo ( thistime )
```

Let's try to make the query run faster.

```
INDEX(someID, status, todo, thistime)
```

would help.

If the tests for otherID are single values, wouldn't this work as well (and faster)?

```
AND otherID IN ( ?, ?, ? )
```

If there are lists, then how about

```
AND otherID IN CONCAT_WS(',', ?, ?, ?)
```

What is `months_todo`?  If it is a function, let's see it.  It also looks like `thissstuff(...)` is a function; let's see it.

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting the query was the issue more so than the system. After researching the months_todo is a function MONTHNAME(). There are a lot of queries similar to this that will need revising. Would adding another reader specifically for these types of reports prevent aurora from locking up everything?

Comment: So, are you taking a slice of all, say, Julys?  That is lumping together last July and all previous Julys?

Comment: @RickJames When your advice has been implemented, ask Harpua to visit www.mysqlservertuning.com  for high performance tuning assistance, please.  Thanks

Comment: We rewrote the query using IN statements. This can be multiple months, but yes grouped by all July's over the years. Thank you for the link I will definitely look into this.